# MoveIt - unable to identify any set of controllers

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, arm-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone!
Actually i `m working with MoveIt! To start, I have watched this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6bBxfD_bYs

i did the same, i can see my robot in rviz (Kuka kr150 3100 prime), i can rotate and etc. But when i press "Execute", nothing happend - i only see error:

```
[ERROR] [1555085718.387324665]: Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints: [ base_link__link_01 link_01__link_02 link_02__link_03 link_03__link_04 link_04__link_05 link_05__link_06 ]
[ERROR] [1555085718.387367066]: Known controllers and their joints:

[ERROR] [1555085718.387435223]: Apparently trajectory initialization failed
```

I try to check everything but nothing happend.

Here are my files:
controller.yaml

```
    controller_list:
 - name: JointPositionController
   action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
   type: FollowJointTrajectory
   default: true
   joints:
     - base_link__link_01
     - link_01__link_02
     - link_02__link_03
     - link_03__link_04
     - link_04__link_05
     - link_05__link_06
```

-joint_names.yaml

```
controller_joint_names: [base_link__link_01, link_01__link_02, link_02__link_03, link_03__link_04, link_04__link_05, link_05__link_06]
```

-mrm_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml

```
    <launch>
  <rosparam file="$(find myrobot_moveit_config)/config/controller.yaml"/>
  <param name="use_controller_manager" value="false"/>
  <param name="trajectory_execution/execution_duration_monitoring" value="false"/>
  <param name="moveit_controller_manager" value="moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager"/>
</launch>
```

-myrobot_planning_execution.launch

```
<launch>
 
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find myrobot_moveit_config)/config/joint_names.yaml"/>
 
  <include file="$(find myrobot_moveit_config)/launch/planning_context.launch" >
    <arg name="load_robot_description" value="true" />
  </include>
 
  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
    <param name="/use_gui" value="false"/>
    <rosparam param="/source_list">[/joint_states]</rosparam>
  </node>
 
  <include file="$(find myrobot_moveit_config)/launch/move_group.launch">
    <arg name="publish_monitored_planning_scene" value="true" />
  </include>
 
  <include file="$(find myrobot_moveit_config)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch">
    <arg name="config" value="true"/>
  </include>
 
</launch>
```

I would be very grateful for Your help!

Pawel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320990/moveit---unable-to-identify-any-set-of-controllers/) by [Pawel_www](https://answers.ros.org/users/40324/pawel_www/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2019-04-12

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pawel_www](https://answers.ros.org/users/40324/pawel_www/) on 2019-04-13**:
Can anyone help me?

**Comment by [sw14928](https://answers.ros.org/users/42538/sw14928/) on 2019-06-17**:
Hi, i am receiving exactly the same error for exactly the same robot! Did you ever work this one out? Cheers

**Comment by [Pawel_www](https://answers.ros.org/users/40324/pawel_www/) on 2019-06-23**:
Hi,
I had found that I didn't have follow_joint_trajectory service, so Moveit couldnt find those controllers.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K09E-_2M-vQ&list=PLK0b4e05LnzbrLrLhOhSvLdaQZOsJl59N&index=13

**Comment by [sw14928](https://answers.ros.org/users/42538/sw14928/) on 2019-06-24**:
Ah ok, I managed to solve mine in the end. I discovered the controller naming was wrong in one of my config files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I always encountered this problem when using moveit setup assistant to create a package.

To fix it go to  /your_moveit_package/config/ros_controllers.yaml. There always lies a blank controller list as such **controller_list: []**. Just remove the brackets and add your controller name with type.  As mentioned in the previous comments it must be of type "FollowJointTrajectory"

A snippet of my ros_controllers.yaml after making the change

```
hardware_interface:
  joints:
    - panda_joint1
    - panda_joint2
    - panda_joint3
    - panda_joint4
    - panda_joint5
    - panda_joint6
    - panda_joint7
    - panda_finger_joint1
  sim_control_mode: 1  # 0: position, 1: velocity
# Publish all joint states
# Creates the /joint_states topic necessary in ROS
joint_state_controller:
  type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
  publish_rate: 50
controller_list:
  - name: panda_arm_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    default: true
    joints:
      - panda_joint1
      - panda_joint2
      - panda_joint3
      - panda_joint4
      - panda_joint5
      - panda_joint6
      - panda_joint7
  - name: panda_hand_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    default: true
    joints:
      - panda_finger_joint1
      - panda_finger_joint2
```

---

Originally posted by [venkys](https://answers.ros.org/users/58650/venkys/) with karma: 96 on 2020-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harunresul](https://answers.ros.org/users/70259/harunresul/) on 2021-02-17**:
Hi. I am having the same problem. There was no problem you mentioned in my controller.yaml file. Same as the one you shared but still having the same problem. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I faced the same issue when I was trying to use an example package that uses Moveit.

In my case, I forget to install Moveit package on the ROS, so I solved the issue by running:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-moveit
```

---

Originally posted by [Moneera Banjar](https://answers.ros.org/users/60255/moneera-banjar/) with karma: 108 on 2020-10-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2